# submit always redirect to same page action doesnt work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

im creating a form that will change/update my ticket status with select option, but whenever i submit. It just goes to self page. this is the address "http://localhost/support/admin-post.php?td=10&id=1" when i click submit, this will happen "http://localhost/support/admin-post.php?ticketstats%5B%5D=Pending#". It should go to "status-update.php". i tried putting it in  still not working,i tried using  but cant get the select value thats why i chose php method instead, here's my code

```
<div class="hide" id="status">
            <form id="myform" role="form" action="ticket.php" method="POST">
        <select class="form-control" type="text" name="ticketstats[]">
            <option><?php echo $status ?></option>
            <option class="disabled">--------------</option>
            <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
            <option value="Open">Open</option>
            <option value="Closed">Closed</option>
        </select> 
            <input class="btn pull-right" type="submit"> 
            <a class="btn pull-left" id="cancelstatus" href="#">Cancel</a>
            </form>
    </div>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    foreach ($_POST['ticketstats'] as $select)
    {

        echo "<script>window.open('status-update.php?    td=$ticketid&id=$empinfoid&stats=$select','_self')</script>";
    }
}
?>


    <a class="pull-right" id="editstatus" href="#">Change</a>
    <div id="status-duetime" class="post-footer"><?php echo time_elapsed_ago($date) ?> </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and this is my main.js

```
var change = document.querySelector("#editstatus");
var cancel = document.querySelector("#cancelstatus");
var statuss = document.querySelector("#status");
var nowstatus = document.querySelector("#nowstatus");
var statusduetime = document.querySelector("#status-duetime");


change.addEventListener("click",edits)
cancel.addEventListener("click",edits)

function edits() {
if (statuss.className === "hide") {
    statuss.className = "";
    statusduetime.className = "hide";
    nowstatus.className = "hide";
    change.className = "hide";
} else {
    statuss.className = "hide";
    statusduetime.className = "post-footer";
    nowstatus.className = "pending";
    change.className = "pull-right";
}

}
```

and this is my action status-update.php

```
<?php
include("database/db_conection.php");   

$ticketid = $_GET['td'];
$empinfoid = $_GET['id'];

if($_POST) {
$sql = "UPDATE employee_tickets SET TicketStatus='".$_GET['stats']."'         WHERE Id='".$_GET['td']."'";


if (!mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}

echo "<script>window.open('admin-post.php?td=$ticketid&id=$empinfoid','_self')</script>";
$conn->close();

}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont give the submit button a `name="???"` attribute you cannot test for it in your PHP

So change this line to

```
<input name="submit" class="btn pull-right" type="submit"> 
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And this line in your PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

Will have something to test.

It would also be a good idea to get rid of the space in this line

```
echo "<script>window.open('status-update.php?    td=$ticketid&id=$empinfoid&stats=$select','_self')</script>";
                                             ^^^^
```

Also your forms `action="ticket.php"` is not going to run the script `status-update.php` it will run `ticket.php`

Comment: tried it but still same but i the name of the input shows too "http://localhost/support/admin-post.php?ticketstats%5B%5D=Closed&submit=Submit#" ... i realize that at "<form action="">" is really not working, i tried different .php site still not working. do you want to see the whole codes?

Comment: No. By the way, you are posting `localhost` links that are useless to anybody not on your PC

Comment: yes because the company will use it by local xampp. im just On the job training student.

Comment: sorry, i solved it, there's a extra code that interfering my code so thats why my submit button is taking action by itself